# AWX to Jump Host: Connection timed out during banner exchange

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I'm trying to use a jump/bastion host to connect to other hosts that are within a private subnet. I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/tmp/awx_50_8n6bocmz/cp/1f25cf0a60\" does not exist\r\ndebug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -W 10.0.15.63:8888 -q user@123.123.989.4\r\ndebug3: timeout: 10000 ms remain after connect\r\ndebug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0\r\ndebug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4\r\ndebug1: permanently_drop_suid: 0\r\nConnection timed out during banner exchange",
    "unreachable": true,
    "changed": false
}
```

I'm trying to connect to the hosts via a bastion. I'm using AWX/Ansible Tower.

CentOS 7
AWX 6.1.0
Ansible 2.8

This is my current config:

```
ansible_connection: ssh
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@123.123.989.4"'
ansible_ssh_port: 8888
ansible_user: user
host_key_checking: false
pipelining: true
```

The jump host ssh key has also been added into awx and is used in job templates, however I'm still not able to create the ssh tunnel to access the hosts in the private subnet through the jump host.

It's probably something simple that I'm missing but I just can't see it! Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: did you found any help with this

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a tunnel.

open a shell and run:

```
ssh -f -N -D 1085 -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=60 user@123.123.989.4:8888
```

and after change the yaml file as below:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: -o ProxyCommand="/bin/nc -x 127.0.0.1:1085 %h %p"
```

and re-try to run ansible-playbook